# Probability that no student sits on the same seat at two different days

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A certain class has 20 students, and meets on Mondays and Wednesdays in a classroom
>   with exactly 20 seats. In a certain week, everyone in the class attends both days. On
>   both days, the students choose their seats completely randomly (with one student per
>   seat). Find the probability that no one sits in the same seat on both days of that week. (Introduction to Probability, Blitzstein and Nwang, p.38)

- Let $E$ be the event that no student is on the same seat, and $E^c$ that at least one student is on the same seat, so $P(E) = 1 - P(E^c)$.
- Let $A_i$ be the event that the $i^{th}$ student is on the same seat.
- $P(E^c) = P(\cup_{i=1}^{20} A_i)$
- $P(A_i) = 1/n$; $P(A_i \cap A_j) = 1/(n(n-1))$; $P(\cap_{i=1}^{t \leq 20} A_i) = 1/(\binom{n}{i}i!)$

Hence, $P(E^c) = \sum_{i=1}^{20} \binom{n}{i} * \frac{1}{\binom{n}{i}i!} * (-1)^{i+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{20} 1/i! (-1)^{i+1} = 0.632$, and so we get $P(E) = 0.368$

Is there a more straightforward way to arrive at the same answer? Any intuition?

In R

```
    n <- 20
    out <- replicate(1e5, {
      1-any(sample(n)==sample(n))
    })
    mean(out)
    > 0.3703
```

**EDIT**

Basen on the answers and comments, I found that I reinvented the wheel (although good exercise for me).
\begin{equation}
1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!} = 1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} = \frac{(-1)^0}{0!} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} = \frac{!n}{n!}
\end{equation}

Thus, the simple answer is the number of derangements (subfactorial factor) over the number of combinations.

Comment: This is a classical problem. Wikipedia has a good article, please see derangements.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you for the hint, I didn't know that.

Comment: Your Inclusion/Exclusion argument gives the right answer, and is probably nicest. There are other approaches, one can get a recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically finding the number of derangements of $20$ elements over the number of possible arrangements $20!$. (Yes, this indeed is. We "set" the Monday arrangement. Then the Wednesday arrangement should have no similar seat for a person).

Then just search online regarding the number of derangement's closed form.

Answer (score 0):

On Monday the students can sit where they want. On Wednesday every student have to choose a seat, which he/she didn´t choose on Monday.

The first student can choose 19 of the 20 chairs : $p=\frac{19}{20}$

The second student can choose 18 of the 19 remaining chairs : $p=\frac{18}{19}$

$\huge{\vdots}$

The 19th student can choose 1 of the 2 chairs : $p=\frac{1}{2}$

The 20th student have to choose the remaining chair : $p=1$

If you multiply all these probabilities, you will get the answer. Many factors can be cancelled out.

Comment: I think you will find that this is not right. It already does not work at $n=3$.

Comment: At the first sight, it seems perfectly correct to me @AndréNicolas. Could you post your solution to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Check that it doesn't  work for $n=3$, $n=4$ where you can readily compute. My solution would probably be the one given by Dominik.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see. My (simple) calculation works only for a given arrangement on Monday.

Comment: @calculus: Fixing the Monday arrangement is a good idea for the analysis. But for $n=3$ there are only $2$ derangements, probability is $2/6$. Your method gives $1/2$. For $n=4$ the actual probability is $9/24$, and your method gives $(3/4)(2/3)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas This is what I meant. Thanks for your reaction.